# How to install Libconfig for Eclipse -C on Windows?

Tags: c, config, libconfig

Could someone tell me the steps to install the [LibConfig](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig) library on Eclipse running C in a windows system.

Comment: Hi again, Anamika :) there should be some tutorials out there. Let me google this for you: https://www.google.de/search?q=eclipse+include+lib&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=66CjVbyTOYXVyAOxzbjQDQ

Comment: @jwsc: Hello :) Thank you for that. I have tried the links but even after adding the path of the downloaded libconfig library, the eclipse software refuses to acknowledge it..